# Why can I not change mysql int value?

Tags: mysql, sql

It seems like a bug because when I set the integer value on a column it says it has been changed successfully but nothing happens and the integer value remains blank.

I can't use the database because I get the error that all my integer columns have incorrect integer values, but when I try to change them to int(11) e.g. nothing is happening.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I can set columns with varchar datatypes to have values and they work fine.

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'topic_id' at row 1 in C:\wamp64\www\mycode\upload2.php on line 32
>
> mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'topic_id' at row 1 in C:\wamp64\www\mycode\upload2.php on line 32

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE `topics` CHANGE `topic_id` `topic_id` INT(11) NOT NULL 
AUTO_INCREMENT; 
// This isn't changing the int value at all!
```

Comment: You can't alter a column from varchar to int if any of the existing rows have non-numeric values in them. Update the rows first, then apply the `ALTER`.

Comment: `Incorrect integer value: ''...` which part of this error message is unclear? Use some debugging to determine why you have an empty string there instead of an integer and fix it in your code.

Comment: Thanks guys I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors in what you are attempting to do.

First, there is the problem that the values in the table are not integers.

Second, you cannot set a column to auto-increment unless it is the primary key.

One option is to drop the primary key and auto-increment idea.  Then you can update the values to `NULL` and change the column to an `int`:

```
update topics
    set topic_id = null
    where topic_id regexp '[^0-9]';

ALTER TABLE `topics` CHANGE `topic_id` `topic_id` INT(11) ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88beae7ef8ad7f2fa8d344255d401457) is a db<>fiddle.

If you really want `topic_id` to be an auto-increment primary key, then I would suggest recreating the table.  Something like this:

```
create table temp_topics as
    select *
    from topics;

drop table topics;  -- be very careful here!

create table topics (
    topic_id int auto_increment primary key,
    . . .   -- the rest of the columns
);

insert into topics (<list of columns here>)
    select <list of columns here>
    from temp_topics;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna change a value you have to update that row.
what you are trying to do is wrong , int data type has fixed length (4 bytes), so when you give it a length , it actually doesn't mean anything and its been ignored by the sql engine

see MySql Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

numeric data types are divided into 3 categoies :

- Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT
- Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value) - DECIMAL, NUMERIC
- Floating-Point Types (Approximate Value) - FLOAT, DOUBLE

Comment: Thanks I thought you had to specify an integer lenght/value for int data types. Thanks for the help.